# iOS Push Notification - check if the banner is showing when app is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I have a VoIP app, where the incoming call notification is very important.

The problem is, sometimes I don't get the push notification (even Apple said it's not guaranteed). But, I do have a mechanism to notice that an call is coming while the app is in the background.

So, what I want to do is.. still use Push Notification as the main handler for incoming call (because it handles the situation when app is closed). However, if the push notification failed to deliver and my app gets the call invite, I will raise a local notification, telling user that you have an incoming call.

My question is... how can I check if a notification is showing before I decide whether to fire a local notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no API to get any information about the state of your notifications. Since you’re making a VoIP app, you have the option to have it get woken up for incoming data, which would let you post your “incoming call” notification whenever you need it—see the “Configuring Sockets for VoIP Usage” section [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12).

Comment: I think I've partially followed the tips to have the app Keep-Alive and listen to incoming data.. does it mean that I should only use local "incoming call" notification and drop the push one?

Comment: Yep, exactly. The push notification should be redundant.

Comment: If the app is closed, then I won't be able to get anything? That's a new problem then..

Comment: It shouldn’t be. The entire point of the VoIP multitasking system I described is to make such apps possible. The system should launch your app at startup and bring it back up if it dies. I suggest trying it out.

Comment: I tried. It worked. But if I kill the app (swipe up from multitask panel), then it would stop working.

Comment: Plausible. When your server doesn’t have a connection open to a given user, it should probably fall back to your existing push-notification mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can only detect the notification when the user taps on the banner OR if the app is open when the notification comes. So I can't see a way to detect if the notification has come yet or not. Just adding to the pain, push notification is famous for its unreliability.

Comment: agreed. such a pain. I think Noah's suggestion is good to go. trying now.